# Retrieve visitor's Google query, pass it to the URL parameters and collect it for analytics purposes

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-search

I've noticed several times that **after clicking on a Google search result**, the **URL** of the page I land on **contains my exact search query**.
This information is most likely collected for analytics purposes, *i.e. which query has the best conversion rate on the shop.*

I'd also like to be able to retrieve this data on my stores.
I asked ChatGPT, and strangely enough, it couldn't answer... It doesn't seem to know about this technique.

Does anyone know what it's called and how to configure it? Thanks in advance!